# jQuery Input value empty after ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm using a jquery ajax call to get a partial razor view from a controller.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    url: url,
    async: false,
    data: JSON.stringify(data)
}).success(function(result) {
    container.html(result);
}).fail(function(result) {
    // fail 
});
```

This works fine and the html that is returned is a form with a few text inputs.  If I view the element, the value of the input is set by what came back from the call.

Example:

```
<input class="valid" id="ItemId" name="ItemId" type="text" value="ItemValue">
```

When I try and use additional jquery on this element, the value is always blank and when I do a selector on the element, the element is different than what shows in the chrome inspect element.

Code to bind to element and to select:

```
$(document).on("blur", "#ItemId", function(e) {
    var itemId = $("#" + e.target.id).val();
}
```

If I type in "NewValue" into the input field, the on blur event does get called, but itemId here is "" and the element looks like this in the chrome console:

```
 <input class="valid" id="ItemId" name="ItemId" type="text" value>
```

I would expect value="NewValue".  What am I missing or doing incorrectly?

Note:  this jQuery code all works fine if I render the partial view by razor without retrieving it from jquery ajax.  The input values work as expected.

Comment: Did you try just `var itemId = this.value`, and you're sure there is **only one** element with that ID.

Comment: var itemId = $("#" + e.target.id).val() -> Here you just assigning the value to another variable. Where is the part where you actually set the value of that element?

Comment: The value is set by the HTML being returned by the Ajax request. The input comes with a value that was rendered by razor.  In my example (the first element) the value is "ItemValue". This is confirmed in the element inspector in chrome.  But when jquery selects it the element has no value.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot `)};`

```
$(document).on("blur", "#ItemId", function(e) {
    var itemId = $("#" + e.target.id).val();
});
```